# Programmatically import Asset in Hierarchy Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a schoolproject we're working on a project for loading BIM-models into unity. We are working with .ifc files, which we convert to .dae for the time being. We created a script for importing the files using `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel`. We are using IFCOpenshell's IFCConvert (a command line utility).

This goes well, and the Asset shows up in the Assets folder. The only thing left to do now, is importing the asset runtime into the Hierarchy ***without dragging it into the scene or hierarchy ***.

We've tried to use a WWW stream to get the file and assign AssetBundles to it and a few other methods, but no luck yet.

Comment: BIM is an abbreviation for Building Information Modeling and is used for modeling buildings before the actual creation of the buildings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_information_modeling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"The only thing left to do now, is importing the asset runtime into the Hierarchy"*

Unless I misunderstand you: for items in "Project" (ie, your assets), if you want to put them in the current scene .. drag them in to the scene.

(ie, drag them either in to the Heirarchy panel or just literally in to the middle of the scene Editor.)

Are you saying you're trying to *automate* this ??  (I don't really see how you could - any button you added would be more difficult than .. just dragging them in.)

---

If you are simply asking how to load (at runtime) Resources, just look in to

```
Resources.LoadAll()
```

You'll learn that you have to keep the items in a "Resources/" folder and so on.  It is well documented.  There are 1000s of QA on the topic. Example code fragment

```
ra = Resources.LoadAll("VO/", typeof(AudioClip) ).Cast<AudioClip>().ToArray();
```

It is beyond the scope of a QA site to provide a tutorial on "Resources" but you can instantly find this on Unity3d.com.

Note that if, very simply, you just want to use a particular model in the build. Do nothing more than, drag it to the scene and place it where you want.  Then in code just

```
  public GameObject yourBuilding;
```

and use **inspector-dragging** to link that variable as you wish. Then you can use that variable as you wish. Note that for large complicated models, often you will go ahead and just have different inspector variables for the different parts, rather than even bothering to drill-down.  (So, you might have "hospital", "eastWing" "corridor" .. etc. and just go ahead and "inspector-drag" those.)

Comment: Yes that is right, i'll update the question. We want the asset to be loaded at runtime so it appears in the scene.

Comment: Maybe we are not asking the right question. The problem is that at runtime, a 3D model has to be imported and displayed on the screen, where the 3D model can be manipulated (using a zSpace tablet (http://zspace.com/)). We now can import a model, but displaying it is a problem now. We can drag the imported 3D model at runtime in the hierarchy. This is why we believe this can be automated.

Comment: I believe you're simply looking for "Resources".  Glance here at the doco http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html  Note that indeed Unity can be confusing, even for expert programmers who have not previously fooled-around with Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Previously created the resources folder and tried to load using your method, only that didn't work and we quickly gave up on this. It does work now, however! :) Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: no problem don't hesitate to ask anything on here.  Note that (and this always annoys me) you can have "as many Resource folders" as you want.  You can either think of this as handy, or messy, depending on your upbringing :)  Note that there are other "special" folder names such as Editor. It's worth looking in to this topic, "special folder names in Unity"!

Comment: Thanks Joe, will do! :)